# Creating a 5D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a gray image in which I want to map every pixel to N other matrices of size LxM.How do I initialize such a matrix?I tried
 `result=numpy.zeros(shape=(i_size[0],i_size[1],N,L,M))` for which I get the Value Error 'array is too big'.Can anyone suggest an alternate method?

Comment: Are you sure you need a 5D array as the amount of data is in the Range of N^5 which gets very fast very big.

Comment: you can try to create such an array using np.tile and list.append.

Comment: I need to create a nested array,and np.tile and list.append don't seem to work.What I need is something like a cell in Matlab-where every element in the array contains another array within.

Comment: How big is `i_size[0]*i_size[1]*N*L*M`?

Comment: Calculate what Eric said (and maybe also how much memory that actually is... I am not certain, but if you have a 32bit version changing to 64 bit might help you (if the size isn't totally insane anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, every pixel in the gray image is mapped to a single pixel in `N` other images. In that case, the map array is `numpy.zeros((i.shape[0], i.shape[1], N, 2), dtype=numpy.int32)` since you need to store 1 x and 1 y coordinate into each other `N` arrays, not the full Nth array every time.  Using integer indices will further reduce memory use.

Then `result[y,x,N,0]` and `result[y,x,N,1]` are the `y` and `x` mappings into the Nth image.